# Gain administrator privileges in Windows Embedded Standard 7

Tags: c#, windows, administrator, windows-embedded-standard

Am asking on how to gain administrator privileges in Windows Embedded Standard 7, i have an embedded machine that works with WES7 and i can't access some of the developers needed peripherals in order to perform some developing stuff like : RS323 Port, even more i can't modify some system files in order to control the startup applications or control the kernel, eventually i can't remove some files like : pictures or txt files that i've created before, but i have done this through command prompt, just to remember, am working in C#.

[image: You can't remove a picture]

[image: pic]

Here i can't access COM port when i try to send data through it :

[image: Program crushed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have founded the solution : i've stopped the process **"Server.exe"** in the directory : **"c:/data "** that have been taking the COM port to control the machine over wifi, and now i can have the full access to the COM port, another thing, i can now modify the system simply by unlocking the hard drive by typing in **CMD** the command : **"fbwfmgr /disable"**.

**+1 Please if it helped** :)